# Blender unable to see image texture file from usdz model

Tags: import

I have the following model downloaded.

It previews fine on macOS quick look.

[image]

but if I open it in blender using the import

it shows this

[image]

How to fix?

usdz file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tt3u2rwilnkcbbu63g042/model.usdz?rlkey=h1xp2j4ybpwgr0bgyvkbq6gma&dl=0

Comment: Your screenshot is taken in Solid [viewport shading mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html), this doesn't show textures by default. Have you tried material or rendered ?

Comment: As @L0Lock already said, you are looking at it in _Solid_ shading mode. When you switch to _Material Preview_ or _Rendered_, everything is fine with the model. Please do at least a few beginner tutorials to learn the basic use of Blender and the _3D Viewport_.